# How do i get Ubuntu 13.04 installed in HP Pavilion dv4 series Entertainment Notebook PC

Tags: 13.04, hp, hp-pavilion

I have HP Pavilion dv4-1204tu Notebook Entertainment PC. I have installed Ubuntu 13.04

How do I get all the devices running inside notebook to function on Ubuntu 13.04?

(Devices Like some shortcut buttons etc.)

There is a panel of shortcut buttons like volume buttons/media buttons.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "devices like some shortcut buttons". Please give more details about the problem in order to receive a useful answer.

Comment: Devices like shortcut button in the panel above keyboard. The panel has touch button (dedicated) volume buttons and media buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You need only to install.  Ubuntu standartly support those buttons so i already use on my hp. İf you will get wifi problem only install it.

Comment: For sound. İf you cant use it. İ have a question. Can you volume up with mouse to click?